# Seeing phone calls on my computer

Tags: linux, networking, phone, caller-id

I would like to setup my computer similar to how some TVs are set up, namely where when someone calls I get a small reminder in the corner with their number and caller id.

This solution would have to work on Linux, and be for only my computer out of the three in the house.

We don't have the TV thing setup, however. Our connection is just modem > Router and then the router has two computers directly attached while mine is off of a somewhere else in the house.

Is this a pipe dream or is it actually possible?

Comment: You forgot to mention the type of phone line, or how that is being terminated.  A SIP connection, or Skype connection obviously should be pretty easy to get callerid to the computer.  Just run the client on the computer.  A POTS, line would be completely different.

Comment: Just a normal wireless housephone that goes on a charger connected to the modem. I'm uh...obviously not knowledgeable enough of this type of thing to really give you a better description, but I'll look into it real quick and see if I can't figure it out

Comment: If you can't even figure out what kind of phone line you have, you might as well stop now.  That's an essential piece of the puzzle, without it, we can't answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have a POTS line, or something that gives you an analog phone phone.

If you want to go the really old-school method you would need to pick up an old PCI voice [modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem#Dialup_modem) that supports caller-id.  Put that in your computer.

The tricky part finding a modem that actually has callerid software that is supported on Linux. I know my old USRobotics 33.6k modem I had two decades ago support reporting caller-id information to Windows, but I don't think anyone ever got the callerid functionality to work on Linux.

Comment: So, I conclude this is impossible in application and extremely hard in theory.